I want to create a /command reload , so that it reloads the config
I would like to create a / reload command in my Minecraft plugin.
So you can reload the configuration even without reloading the server.
It would be very useful, thanks if you help me.
I use Java with a minecraft version in 1.20.4

Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you show what you tried, and where you are stuck? By including your code and others debugging details
